# What is the purpose of com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String?

Tags: java, string

I was writing a Java program, and when I tried to use a string, a suggestion that popped up was `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String`.

What is `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String`, and when should I use it?

I have looked online, but I cannot find the documentation.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a code question, it is a question I asked out of curiosity.

Comment: If you do not know what it is, don't use that suggestion. I am sure you need to use a `java.lang.String`.

Comment: It's an internal class of the JDK and you should never use it directly.

Comment: @Jesper-Would you mind posting complete detail as an answer!

Comment: AND, to be more specific, you should NEVER use anything not in the `java` or `javax`. The classes contained in the `com.sun.org` packages were meant to be used internally, but they (Java) made them public (accidentally) but because many people use them, they kept supporting them.  HOWEVER, they have already announced that they will hide these classes starting in Java 9 or 10 (I can't remember which one).

Comment: @VarmirGarkin- Which editor BTW you are using?

Comment: @Makoto, I see how these two questions are similar, but I don't think that it is a duplicate. It is like asking about JFrame usage versus asking about what is inside of the javax.swing package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can work backwards based on the package name. The first piece that gives us a clue to what it does is *Xpath*. Then there's Apache, which is a the [Apache Software Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Software_Foundation). So it's an API called Xpath from Apache.

[XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) is a language for parsing and processing XML content. It has some simple capabilities such as math or data conversions. In this case, [String](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/swm/jdoc1.7.0_51/com/sun/org/apache/xpath/internal/operations/String.html) is a unary operator that converts text to a String, as opposed to a Number or a boolean. It has one static method `operate`:

```
public XObject operate(XObject right)
            throws TransformerException
```

It takes an XObject of some unknown type and converts it to a String type.

An example snippet of XPath for String conversion would be, at its barest:

```
string($x) //convert variable x to a String
```

You probably would never need to call this, seeing as it is part of an *internal* package. It is most probably used when interpreting XML to get the result as a String for use with other Xpath internal components. Indeed, the returned result is an [XObject](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/swm/jdoc1.7.0_51/com/sun/org/apache/xpath/internal/objects/XObject.html) with a type associated to it, so interpreting it as a normal Java String would break something. It is nice to helpful to know that it's there, and it is `public` per design, but you'd ever use this in the real world unless you're expanding on the xpath API yourself.

[Source Package Tree](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/swm/jdoc1.7.0_51/com/sun/org/apache/xpath/internal/operations/package-tree.html)

Comment: From my side +1,Brilliant Job!

Answer (score 0):

This is a class used by some Apache implementation that unfortunately shows up in your Java CodeAssist.

If you are using Eclipse you can check that out:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/80401/