# String cannot be applied to com.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap

I'm trying to create a `PieChart` in JavaFX, and I want to fill it with data from a `HashMap`.

Here's my code:

```
public Graph(HashMap<String, Double> chartData) {
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry: chartData.entrySet()) {
        String s = entry.getKey();
        new PieChart.Data(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        //System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
    }

    chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
    chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");
}
```

The issue I am facing is that when I try to use `entry.getKey()` as the string, I get the following error:

> Data (java.lang.String, double) in Data cannot be applied to
>   (com.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String, Double).

The String is marked red and when I replace `entry.getKey()` with `"Some text"` it does work. What is the cause?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to have imported the wrong "String" class ( `com.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String`) in your current file and the Data class expects the correct one (`java.lang.String`). Make sure your imports are correct (i.e. remove the import of the first type).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236082/what-is-the-purpose-of-com-sun-org-apache-xpath-internal-operations-string), where the asker has run into a similar problem

Comment: Thanks, must have imported itself and it went unnoticed.

Comment: Yea I will, can't do it within 15 min ;)

Comment: I did the same mistake and I was wondering why my strings does not fit together.

Answer (score 0):

this code snippet:

```
new PieChart.Data(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

`entry.getKey()` is not string

```
String s = entry.getKey();
new PieChart.Data(s, entry.getValue());
```

Try it

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.Data.html